# javascript function currying pass default parameters to outer function in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, parameter-passing, currying

I have some methods in vue.js where I basically recycle same methods for  different components, which means in my method only some small parameters change for the different components. I want to pass those components to my function, and then that function should return another function with its respective own scope of my preevious defined parameter variables, e.g:

`retrieveSomeRoomData: Helper.retrieveData(pagetype = 'someCountry', roomType = 'someRoom')`

now, this retrieveData function is defined in my Helper:

retrieveData: ((pageType, roomType) => {

```
    return ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
        ...doSomething with payload and state, and use the pageType and roomType variables for 
        customizing the function... then return this function
    })();
```

Now I thought the above is possible with function currying, where I pass my custom parameters on the outer function scope inside my real function definition and return that inner customized function... but I get the error that pageType and roomType is not defined... and I am not even sure, if the commit, state and payload parameters of my inner function are getting their parameter values if I use my function like in the above first code line... I pass just some default parameters, but I am not sure if the other parameters for the inner  function get passed... how could I do this the best way?

edit: I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pagetype is not defined
    at eval (actions.js?63e0:13)
    at Module../src/store/actions.js (<anonymous>:9209:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:727:30)
    at fn (<anonymous>:101:20)
    at eval (store.js?07a4:1)
    at Module../src/store/store.js (<anonymous>:9245:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:727:30)
    at fn (<anonymous>:101:20)
    at eval (VM6658 main.js:12)
    at Module../src/main.js (<anonymous>:9197:1)
```

hmm is it just because I have to do const pagetype= 'someCountry' and const roomType?

EDIT: I found  the solution...
I just had to use plain strings as parameters when calling my function:

```
Helper.retrieveData('someCountry','someRoom')
```

Comment: This should work—would you mind providing more details to help debug?

Comment: I edited it in above, maybe I just forgot let or const to define the default parameters? Edit: nope thats not possible apparently ;)

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/PreciousEqualDigits, I don't think assignment of parameters while calling the function is needed

Answer (score 1):

It could be a simple casing error, hard to know without the full code. You have camel case (pageType) in the function definition but no camel case in the error (pagetype).

Comment: hm I just used plain strings as parameters without any assignment then it worked, I checked for camelCase but it wasn't that..